# Pathing Algorithm using pig script

Tags: apache-pig, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I work with a mobile application which has screen name attached to each screen (navigated thru drag/click) user follows to accomplish a task. I have a requirement to record/collect the paths a user follows. I have a table which will collect all the activities a user will do(like navigating thru screens in application). Can anyone suggest thoughts on how it can be implemented using pig scripting?

Comment: see http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.0.0/datafu/pig/stats/MarkovPairs.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I think you ask to implement using python script. I could not understand how it relates to what I need. Can you provide a sample python code with example ?

Comment: I need something like, user1: screen1-> screen2 -> screen3 (final screen) and user2: screen1 -> screen4 -> screen2-> screen3 (final screen). Ultimate goal is to find the most frequent used path by customers. Thanks!